# push difrent object array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a product array and customer array

and i want to add all customer array objects to the product array

```js
    let product = [
      {image:"image1",id:0},
      {image:"image2",id:1},
      {image:"image3",id:2},
      {image:"image4",id:3},
      {image:"image5",id:4}
    ];
    let customer = [
      {user_id:11},
      {user_id:12},
      {user_id:13},
      {user_id:14},
      {user_id:15}
    ];
```

I want this array

```js
    let product = [
      {image:"image1",id:0,user_id:11},
      {image:"image2",id:1,user_id:12},
      {image:"image3",id:2,user_id:13},
      {image:"image4",id:3,user_id:14},
      {image:"image5",id:4,user_id:15}
    ];
```

Comment: Concat them by array.concat()  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? A loop should be enough to solve this.

Comment: `let ar3 = product.concat(customer)`

Comment: @YAKA concat is not my answer

Comment: Your edit still calls for a simple loop. We are not here to do your homework. So please add what you have tried so far, what problems you have, any errors, ...

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no clear relationship between customer, you can do this way

```
product = product.map((productItem, index) => ({
    ...productItem,
    user_id: customer[index].user_id
}));
```

which will output,

```
[
   {
      "image":"image1",
      "id":0,
      "user_id":11
   },
   {
      "image":"image2",
      "id":1,
      "user_id":12
   },
   {
      "image":"image3",
      "id":2,
      "user_id":13
   },
   {
      "image":"image4",
      "id":3,
      "user_id":14
   },
   {
      "image":"image5",
      "id":4,
      "user_id":15
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
product.forEach((x, index) => Object.assign(x, customer[index]));
```